# $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R^3$ such that any 3 vectors in $S$ spans a $2$ dimensional subspace then $S$ also spans $2$ dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R^3$ such that any 3 vectors in $S$ spans a $2$ dimensional subspace then $S$ also spans $2$ dimensional space ?

I think this should be true but i dont have a proper argument.Its clear that any $3$ vectors of $S$ make a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ ,i also know that finitely many planes cannot cover whole of $\mathbb R^3$.How can we complete this argument?

Comment: S can have at most 2 linearly independent elements. Hence the span will be of two dimension.

Comment: Suppose $S$ does not span a two dimensional space Then, there exist at least three linearly independent vectors in $S$, which span that space. But then this is a contradiction.

Comment: Keep in mind this is not true in general if $S$ contains fewer than 3 elements, for instance $S=\{(1,0,0),(3,0,0)\}$ vacuously satisfies the hypothesis but not the conclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> There are two linear independent vectors $s_{1}, s_{2} \in S$. Just take three (distinct) vectors in $S$, and see that two of them must be linearly independent.

**Hint 2**

> For each $s \in S$, the subpace generated by $s_{1}, s_{2}, s$ has dimension $2$.

**Hint 3**

> $s$ is a linear combination of $s_{1}, s_{2}$.

Comment: Thanks..it was much easier than what i thought. and +1 of course!

Comment: @VictorBarg, thx!

Comment: Nice answer @Andreas